# Join 2 tables to produce desired output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as following:

*Products* table:

```
ProductID   Name
   1        Condensed cheese
   2        Milk
```

*Prices* table:

```
ProductID   Currency   Price
    2          EUR       1.50
    2          USD       1.74
    2          JPY     194.624
    1          EUR       0.99
    1          USD       1.15
```

I am learning SQL and wondering what would be SQL statement to join 2 above tables to produce this output:

```
ProductID     Name               EUR     USD     JPY
    1         Condensed cheese   0.99    1.15    NULL
    2         Milk               1.50    1.74    194.624
```

Comment: Organizing data like that is typically called 'pivoting'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [Pivot Table problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table). You will need to use conditional aggregation with `Group By` clause.

- Do an [`Inner Join`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) between the two tables using `ProductID`.
- We do a [`Group By`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) on `ProductId` and `Name`, since you want a single row for a productid with all the prices in the same row.
- Now, we will use conditional function [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to determine price for a specific currency column. If the currency code matches for that column, we consider that price value, else we consider `null`. So, for example, in a column aliased `EUR`, we will have `null` values for rest of the currencies (except EUR). We will then use [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function to  ensure that we consider the corresponding currency price only.
- If there is no price value for a specific currency in the `Prices` table, it shall come as `null` value (all currencies will show `null` and `Max(null, null, ...) = null`
- Eventually we `Order By ProductID ASC` to get the result [sorted in ascending order](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) by `ProductID`.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT pdt.ProductID, 
       pdt.Name, 
       MAX( IF(prc.Currency = 'EUR', prc.Price, NULL) ) AS EUR, 
       MAX( IF(prc.Currency = 'USD', prc.Price, NULL) ) AS USD, 
       MAX( IF(prc.Currency = 'JPY', prc.Price, NULL) ) AS JPY
FROM Products AS pdt 
INNER JOIN Prices AS prc ON prc.ProductID = pdt.ProductID 
GROUP BY pdt.ProductID, pdt.Name 
ORDER BY pdt.ProductID ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `max()` function with case when

```
select t1.ProductID ,t1.Name,
 max(case when t2.Currenc= 'EUR' then Price end) as EUR,
 max(case when t2.Currenc= 'USD' then Price end) as USD,
 max(case when t2.Currenc= 'JPY' then Price end) as JPY
 from 
Products t1 join Prices  t2 on t1.ProductID =t2.ProductID  
group by t1.ProductID ,t1.Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for not being able to accept more than 1 answer. Madhur Bhaiya answer was more helpful with explanation, I upvoted your answer!

Comment: @meteorzeroo thanks you can accept any one's answer which you think better . but the answer you accepted  is not ansi sql where my answer will fit for any db which is followed by ansi sql. aggregate function not work for NULL but he mentioned that :) you may follow him if you think that is better